# PHP video upload and checking video type

Tags: php, html

I created my upload file with video size and type validation. Only webm, mp4 and ogv file types are allowed and 2gb file size max. My php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    $allowed_extensions = array("webm", "mp4", "ogv");
    $file_name_temp = explode(".", $file_name);
    $extension = end($file_name_temp);
    
    $file_size_max = 2147483648;
    if (!empty($file_name))
    {
        if (($file_type == "video/webm") || ($file_type == "video/mp4") || ($file_type == "video/ogv") &&
            ($file_size < $file_size_max) && in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions))
        {
            if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0)
            {
                echo "Unexpected error occured, please try again later.";
            } else {
                if (file_exists("secure/".$file_name))
                {
                    echo $file_name." already exists.";
                } else {
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "secure/".$file_name);
                    echo "Stored in: " . "secure/".$file_name;
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid video format.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please select a video to upload.";
    }
}
```

My html code:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'am always getting "Invalid video format.". I downloaded webm, mp4 and ogv video files from flowplayer website to test my little upload script.

```
http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm
http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.mp4
http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.ogv
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your extensions were not correctly being validated.. try this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

    $allowed_extensions = array("webm", "mp4", "ogv");
    $file_size_max = 2147483648;
    $pattern = implode ($allowed_extensions, "|");

    if (!empty($file_name))
    {    //here is what I changed - as you can see above, I used implode for the array
        // and I am using it in the preg_match. You pro can do the same with file_type,
        // but I will leave that up to you
        if (preg_match("/({$pattern})$/i", $file_name) && $file_size < $file_size_max)
        {
            if (($file_type == "video/webm") || ($file_type == "video/mp4") || ($file_type == "video/ogv"))
            {
                if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0)
                {
                    echo "Unexpected error occured, please try again later.";
                } else {
                    if (file_exists("secure/".$file_name))
                    {
                        echo $file_name." already exists.";
                    } else {
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "secure/".$file_name);
                        echo "Stored in: " . "secure/".$file_name;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "Invalid video format.";
            }
        }else{
            echo "where is my mojo?? grrr";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please select a video to upload.";
    }
}
```

Comment: You must have something wrong.. copy and paste the code above. I tested this 4 times and works perfectly, also make sure the extension is correct.. make sure its all in lower case just in case to be safe.. although it should not matter.

Comment: I copy your code and test it many times, still getting the "Invalid video format" man. T__T

Comment: you can test it here.. http://hexcoderz.net/temp/postvids/test.php If it does not work try another file.. maybe the file is corrupted or something

Comment: File uploaded successfully. btw I'am working locally(wamp server).

Comment: I tested this locally (linux) as well.. try doing a print_r ($_FILE) to see the type that you are getting.

Comment: in case you are wondering.. refresh http://hexcoderz.net/temp/postvids/test.php. This script will be removed in 1h

Comment: I already copy and paste you code from hexcoderz.net/temp/postvids/test.php

Comment: print_r($_FILES) result:
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => 624x260.mp4 [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: This has nothing to do with the script, there must be something wrong with your server.. yet I am unaware of your server type. Have you tried uploading another file? try one from here http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/http-mp4.htm

Comment: I still can't upload a video. grrr!

Comment: You stated that you are doing this locally correct? what kind of server are you currently running this code on? have you tried searching google? This has never happen to me, so currently I am a bit clueless but I am willing to see what is causing it.

Comment: worked for me on testing.team.pro, again... please check your file

Comment: WTF, you uploaded a .mp4 on my testing server, but I can't upload >.<

Comment: ok, one more time.. try uploading a diff file.. try uploading the same file I did.. now you know that the script does work :)

Comment: Yeah the script works, If I upload larger than 2MB it wont upload.

Comment: You will need to modify php.ini to allow a greater amount. Don't forget to set this as answered once you are completely sure that all is working accordingly

Comment: OK. Thanks for your time and effort @xlordt :D

Answer (score 2):

```js
function fileSelected() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass');
            var input = inputs[0];
            var file = input.files[0];
            var name = file.name;
            var size = file.size;
            var type = file.type;
    //alert("type: "+type);
    if(type!="video/mp4")
    {
     alert("NOT SUITABLE EXTENSION SELECTED");
     
    }
    
            filesArray.push({ name: name, size: size });
        }
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="video/*" class=" form-control btn btn-primary myclass" required name="file1" id="file1" onchange="fileSelected();">
```