# How to validate uploaded file is vidoe file php?

Tags: php, video, contenttype

How can i check uploaded file is video format or any other format.
user can upload any type of video file.

```
echo mime_content_type($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Video Upload And Checking Video Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504290/php-video-upload-and-checking-video-type)

Comment: check [here][1] 
answer already here         


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217964/upload-video-files-via-php-and-save-them-in-appropriate-folder-and-have-a-databa

Answer (score 0):

```
// Type contains video/mp4,video/avi,video/mpeg,video/mpg etc
if(preg_match('/video\/*/',$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'])): 
    echo "THIS IS A VIDEO FILE";
else:
      echo "NOT A VIDEO FILE";           
endif;
```

Comment: Please add more commentary on what you're actually suggesting here; it's not helpful to just provide code as a response as the user will not learn anything from that.